# Get all users/groups having access to a collaboration : BOX API

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

Is there a way to retrive all the users/groups having access to a collaboration : BOX API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API defines a collaboration as an access control list. It's an object that grants a single user (or group) permissions to access a folder, so you can't really have access to a collaboration.

It sounds more like you're asking how you can get a list of all the collaborations on a folder, which you can do with:

```
GET /folders/{id}/collaborations
```

which will return something like:

```
{
    "total_count": 1,
    "entries": [
        {
            "type": "collaboration",
            "id": "14176246",
            "created_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "4276790",
                "name": "David Lee",
                "login": "david@box.com"
            },
            "created_at": "2011-11-29T12:56:35-08:00",
            "modified_at": "2012-09-11T15:12:32-07:00",
            "expires_at": null,
            "status": "accepted",
            "accessible_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "755492",
                "name": "Simon Tan",
                "login": "simon@box.net"
            },
            "role": "editor",
            "acknowledged_at": "2011-11-29T12:59:40-08:00",
            "item": null
        }
    ]
}
```

https://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-view-a-folders-collaborations